# Use Ion Auth BCrypt inside Oauth2

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, bcrypt, codeigniter-4, ion-auth

I'm developing an API using CodeIgniter 4 and OAuth2. I have an existing database that I need to use but the web app is made from CodeIgniter 3 and I used Ion Auth for authentication. How can I compare the given password by the user to the equivalent password in the database using Ion Auth's verify password function? Or is there a way I can compare passwords without Ion Auth at all?

The code snippet I need to change in OAuth2 located in `OAuth2\Storage\Pdo.php`:

```
 protected function checkPassword($user, $password)
{
    return $user['password'] == $this->hashPassword($password);
}

// use a secure hashing algorithm when storing passwords. Override this for your application
protected function hashPassword($password)
{
    return sha1($password);
}
```

I'm not sure how I can do this. Worse case scenario, I'll switch back to CI3 and do another API.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the `checkPassword` function with this:

```
protected function checkPassword($user, $password)
{
    //return $user['password'] == $this->hashPassword($password);
    return password_verify($password, $user['password']);
}
```

That's it!